# How to fix "cannot reinitialize datatable"

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have a data table with twelve(12) columns. I am using PHP to populate the data inside my data table. My problem is I can populate the data table but I am getting "Cannot reinitialize data table" error but I only initialize my table once. How can I fix this and avoid this problem in the future?

Here is my data table using javascript I am using serverside processing to get and populate my data table:

```
table = [
            { "width": "80px", "targets": 0 },
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 1 },
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 2 }, 
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 3 },
            { "width": "120px", "orderable": false, "targets": 4 },
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 5 },
            { "width": "100px", "targets": 6 },
            { "width": "110px", "targets": 7 },
            { "width": "150px", "orderable": false, "targets": 8 },
            { "width": "150px", "orderable": false, "targets": 9 },
            { "width": "150px", "orderable": false, "targets": 10 },
            { "width": "150px", "orderable": false, "targets": 11 }
        ];

        var table = $('#activities-table').DataTable({
            "searching": { "regex": true },
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "scrollY":"500px",
            "scrollX":"300px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "activities-data.php",
                type: "POST",
                "dataType": "json",
                data: {salesman:salesman, startdate:startdate, enddate:enddate, supervisor:supervisor},
                "complete": function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            },
            "columnDefs": table,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
                "zeroRecords": "No data available in table",
                "info": "Showing <b>_START_</b> to <b>_END_ of _TOTAL_</b> entries",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":      "First",
                    "last":       "Last",
                    "next":       "Next",
                    "previous":   "Previous"
                },
                search: "_INPUT_",
                searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
            ]
        });
```

And here is how I populate my data table using PHP
Note: This code will only return one(1) data

```
$salesman = $_POST["salesman"];
$supervisor = $_POST["supervisor"];
$startdate = $_POST["startdate"];
$enddate = $_POST["enddate"];

$request = $_REQUEST;

$whereCondition = "";
$sqlTotal = "";
$sqlRecord = "";

$columns = array(
    0 => 'tblCaf.CAFNo',
    1 => 'EmployeeName',
    2 => 'CustomerName',
    3 => 'ContactPerson',
    4 => 'Activity',
    5 => 'tblCaf.ActivityDate',
    6 => 'tblCaf.StartTime',
    7 => 'tblCaf.EndTime',
    8 => 'tblCaf.StartLocation',
    9 => 'tblCaf.EndLocation',
    10 => 'tblCaf.OtherConcern',
    11 => 'tblCaf.Remarks'
);

if(!empty($request['search']['value'])){
    $whereCondition  .= " AND 
        (tblCaf.CAFNo LIKE '%".$request['search']['value']."%'
        OR EmployeeName.FileAs LIKE '%".$request['search']['value']."%'
        OR CustomerName.FileAs LIKE '%".$request['search']['value']."%'
        OR ContactPerson.FileAs LIKE '%".$request['search']['value']."%')";
}

$sql = "SELECT TOP 50 EmployeeName.FileAs AS Emp, CustomerName.FileAs AS CUS, ContactPerson.FileAs AS CP, tblCaf.CAFNo, tblCaf.CAFDate, tblCaf.StartTime, tblCaf.EndTime, tblCAF.StartLocation, tblCAF.EndLocation, tblCaf.OtherConcern, tblCaf.Remarks
FROM tblCaf
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblContacts AS EmployeeName ON EmployeeName.ContactID = tblCaf.EmployeeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblContacts AS CustomerName ON CustomerName.ContactID = tblCaf.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblContacts AS ContactPerson ON ContactPerson.ContactID = tblCaf.ContactPersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSalesmanSupervisor ON tblSalesmanSupervisor.SalesmanID = tblCaf.EmployeeID
WHERE tblCaf.CAFDate BETWEEN :start AND :end";

$sqlTotal .= $sql;
$sqlRecord .= $sql;

if(isset($whereCondition) && $whereCondition != ""){
    $sqlTotal .= $whereCondition;
    $sqlRecord .= $whereCondition;
}

if($db_conn == "MYSQL"){
    $sqlRecord .= " ORDER BY ". $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']] ." " . $request["order"][0]['dir'] . " LIMIT " . $request["start"] . " ," . $request["length"]. " ";

    $sqlTotal .= " LIMIT 50";
}
else{
    $sqlRecord .= " ORDER BY ". $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']] ." " . $request["order"][0]['dir'];
}

$resultTotal = $conn->prepare($sqlTotal, $cursor);
$resultTotal->bindValue(":start", $startdate);
$resultTotal->bindValue(":end", $enddate);
$resultTotal->execute();

$totalData = $resultTotal->rowCount();

$resultRecords = $conn->prepare($sqlRecord, $cursor);
$resultRecords->bindValue(":start", $startdate);
$resultRecords->bindValue(":end", $enddate);
$resultRecords->execute();

$data = array();

$activities = "";

$i = 1;

$subdata = array();

if($totalData > 0){
    while($row = $resultRecords->fetch()){
        $subdata[] = $row["CAFNo"];

        $subdata[] = strtoupper($row["Emp"]);
        $subdata[] = strtoupper($row["CUS"]);
        $subdata[] = strtoupper($row["CP"]);

        $multiplesql = $conn->prepare("SELECT ActivityID FROM tblCafActivity WHERE CAFNo = :caf", $cursor);
        $multiplesql->bindValue(":caf", $row["CAFNo"]);
        $multiplesql->execute();

        $multiplecount = $multiplesql->rowCount();  

        if($multiplecount > 0){
            while($multiplerow = $multiplesql->fetch()){
                $activitysql = $conn->prepare("SELECT ActivityDescription FROM tblActivity WHERE ActivityID = :act", $cursor);
                $activitysql->bindValue(":act", $multiplerow["ActivityID"]);
                $activitysql->execute();
                $activitycount = $activitysql->rowCount();

                if($activitycount > 0){
                    while($activityrow = $activitysql->fetch()){

                        $activities = strtoupper($activityrow["ActivityDescription"]) . "<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $subdata[] = $activities;
        $subdata[] = date("F j, Y", strtotime($row['CAFDate']));
        $subdata[] = date("h:i:s a", strtotime($row['StartTime']));

        if(empty($row['EndTime'])){
            $subdata[] = "";
        }
        else {
            $subdata[] = date("h:i:s a", strtotime($row['EndTime']));
        }

        $subdata[] = $row['StartLocation'];
        $subdata[] = $row['EndLocation'];

        $subdata[] = strtoupper($row["OtherConcern"]);
        $subdata[] = strtoupper($row["Remarks"]);

        $data[] = $subdata;
    }
}

$json_data = array(
    "draw" => intval($request['draw']),
    "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData),
    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalData),
    "data" => $data
);

print json_encode($json_data);
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: Can you reduce all that code to the minimal parts that trigger the problem? Where exactly is it triggered? Does this affect PHP after all?

Comment: @party-ring I am using MS SQLServer

Comment: @NicoHaase I dont think the php is affected the problem is the data table itself the error is displaying twice

Answer (score 0):

You variable name for columns and table is same i.e "table". table is being called inside data-table initialization as well. Chanege the variable name for columnDefs to something else.

```
var columns= [
            { "width": "80px", "targets": 0 },
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 1 },
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 2 }, 
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 3 },
            { "width": "120px", "orderable": false, "targets": 4 },
            { "width": "120px", "targets": 5 },
            { "width": "100px", "targets": 6 },
            { "width": "110px", "targets": 7 },
            { "width": "150px", "orderable": false, "targets": 8 },
            { "width": "150px", "orderable": false, "targets": 9 },
            { "width": "150px", "orderable": false, "targets": 10 },
            { "width": "150px", "orderable": false, "targets": 11 }
        ];

        var table = $('#activities-table').DataTable({
            "searching": { "regex": true },
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "scrollY":"500px",
            "scrollX":"300px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "activities-data.php",
                type: "POST",
                "dataType": "json",
                data: {salesman:salesman, startdate:startdate, enddate:enddate, supervisor:supervisor},
                "complete": function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            },
            "columnDefs": columns,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "No data available in table",
                "zeroRecords": "No data available in table",
                "info": "Showing <b>_START_</b> to <b>_END_ of _TOTAL_</b> entries",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":      "First",
                    "last":       "Last",
                    "next":       "Next",
                    "previous":   "Previous"
                },
                search: "_INPUT_",
                searchPlaceholder: "Search..."
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code before your ajax call.

```
"destroy": true
```

read more on destroy here: link: https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy

or if it fails, add this

```
"retrieve": true
```

link: https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve